# Syntax for nested signatures?

Tags: signature, ml

In my ml program I am using nested structures to structure my code. I'm defining the signatures for these structures - but I can't really get to have the signatures nested.

Example:

```
structure Example =
struct
  structure Code = 
  struct
    datatype mytype = Mycons of string
  end
end
```

for this I'd like to do something like this:

```
signature EXAMPLE = 
sig
  signature CODE = (* or stucture Code - doesn't matter *)
  sig
    datatype mytype
  end
end
```

Now this doesn't work; I get syntax errors. My questions:

1. Is this a bad idea? If so, why?
2. How do I do it? How do I apply the nested signature to the nested structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax in signatures when having nested structures, requires some getting used to.

When trying to specify the signature if a structure within a signature you do it like this

```
signature JSON =
sig    
  type t

  .. some signature stuff

  structure Converter : sig    
    type json
    type 'a t

    ... Converter specification stuff
    ... using type json as the parent signatures type t    
  end where type json = t    
end
```

See these Hoffman[[.sml](https://github.com/mortenbp/mylib/blob/master/Algorithms/Hoffman.sml)][[.sig](https://github.com/mortenbp/mylib/blob/master/Algorithms/Hoffman.sig)] files for a simple examples of this and have a look at the Tree[[.sig](https://github.com/mortenbp/mylib/blob/master/DataStructures/Tree/Tree.sig)] file for a bit more complex example.

Remember that you need to mention your signature specification in your structure, else it will be pointless to make the signature in the first place.